# How do I get the content of a JavaScript confirmation prompt in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium, how can I get the contents of a JavaScript confirmation prompt?

Screenshot of the prompt: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?a296dd8a59.png

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99045/handling-browser-pop-up-windows-with-selenium

Comment: but i want to get the content of the prompt windows.

Comment: prompt error:There were no confirmations   
how to send the command at the right time???
   selenium default click ok, and do not display the pop-window.

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot shows a JavaScript confirmation prompt. You can use the *Confirmation commands, such as:

```
verifyConfirmation | The changes you made will be lost
assertConfirmation | The changes you made will be lost
```

By default Selenium will accept the confirmation, however to influence this use the `chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation` or `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation` commands.

With Selenium RC you'd use `getConfirmation`.

Selenium reference for above commands:

- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#storeConfirmation
- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation
- http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#chooseOkOnNextConfirmation

Comment: You need to make sure you use the command at the correct time. It looks like at the time your command is sent the confirmation prompt is not present. What triggers the prompt? If it's page load/unload then Selenium might not be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the popup is alert,confirmation or prompt. All three has different functions. Check the source for the same and use the appropriate command in RC or IDE