# Selenium: Testing pop-up windows

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have an issue when trying to test a web application with Selenium/Python. Basically I can't test elements of a pop-up window.

**A scenario:** I can test all elements for a page. But when I go to click on a button that opens up a small pop up box I can't test the elements on the popup. It's like the pop up isn't in focus or active.

I can test elements on the next page. For example click a button, brings me on to next page, and I can work with elements on the 'next' page. So it the problem seems to be popup specific.

I could post code but to be honest it might confuse at this stage. I may post code in a later post, thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is a property called **switch_to**

> **Q: How do I handle pop up windows?**

A: WebDriver offers the ability to cope with multiple windows. This is done by using the `WebDriver.switch_to.window(knownName)` method to switch to a window with a known name.

If the name is not known, you can use `WebDriver.window_handles` to obtain a list of known windows.

You may pass the handle to `switch_to.window(handleName)`

For example I used `driverName.switchTo.window(driverName.getWindowHandle())` to get a hold of popups for which I didn't want to look for names.

Additional references:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using selenium RC. Can this be adapted in RC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99045/handling-browser-pop-up-windows-with-selenium this seems to be related to RC. I havn't used RC, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: No probs, thanks for the web driver solution though, will come in handy

Answer (score 0):

For the Selenium RC API, you need to use the SelectWindow command to switch to the pop-up window.  The window can be specified either by its name (as specified on the JavaScript `window.open()` function) or its title.  To switch back to the main window, use `SelectWindow(None)`.